# MS-sql retrieve grade data from the oldest students

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ8aT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guYsU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b3F1.png)

I'm very new to SQL. I'm trying to retrieve some data from my database. The SQL-database I am using is MS sql and the server has three tables available:

students
Grades
Grade_types

I am trying to get grade data from the 100 students with the oldest ENROLL_DATE, the ENROLL_DATE is in the table Students.

This is the statement I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
 Select top (100) * from students order by ENROLL_DATE ASC inner join grades on students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID order by ENROLL_DATE
```

Comment: Try and remove the first `ORDER BY`. It's syntactically not allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. There can only be one ORDER BY and it must go at the end:

```
Select top 100 *
from students inner join grades on students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID
order by ENROLL_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that students can have more than one grade, then you want to select the 100 students first, and then retrieve all the grades for them:

```
Select *
from (select top (100) s.*
      from students s
      order by ENROLL_DATE ASC
     ) s inner join
     grades g
     on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
order by ENROLL_DATE;
```

Note that you may want a `left join` if the older students don't have grades.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but unfortunately they didn't work :( I have uploaded some pictures of the tables.